# Core Data one-to-many relationship gets deleted when creating a new one

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, one-to-many

I'm a novice regarding Core Data, and exploring the way it works, I find myself stuck in yet another problem.

I'm fetching data from two separate web services, one to get a JSON list of employees, another one to get a JSON list of companies.
The companies list their employees as an array of employeeID, while the employees list the companies for which they work as a comma separated string, not intended to be a reference.

So here's what I do:

1) I make sure to start with an empty database

2) I populate my core data from the employees feed

3) I populate my company entities, setting a relation to each employee they have (that's where the problem comes)

4) I want to display the list of companies, with their associated employees

The problem is, a company can hire several employees, and each employee can work for 0 to n enterprise.
So when I create my first company, I link it to its employees and everything works fine, but when I create my second company and link it to an employee of the previous company, the previous company loses its relationship to that employee.

After some research, I didn't find a similar problem (maybe because I'm still a core data novice I'm not looking in the right place), but I found this post:
http://codekea.com/3J1AZNYRkAMr/setting-core-data-relationship-reusing-same-object-removes-previous-relation.html
Which seems to be the exact same problem.
As the answer didn't solve anything in my case (the code won't compile anymore), I thought I'd create a sample project to illustrate it.

Said project can be downloaded from here to test:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qi65sh52wwe6ws3/test.zip?dl=0

My code is as follows (I use SwiftyJSON):

```
let mURLEmployees       = NSURL(string: "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZhmHCmwQ")
let mURLCompanies       = NSURL(string: "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LCbvyvqv")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //==============================================
    // 1)
    //      EMPTY THE DATABASE
    //==============================================


    var error: NSError? = nil

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")

    let entities = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject]

    for entity in entities {
        context.deleteObject(entity)
    }

    let request2 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Company")

    let entities2 = context.executeFetchRequest(request2, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject]

    for entity in entities2 {
        context.deleteObject(entity)
    }

    if !context.save(&error) {
        println("An error occured while deleting entities : \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }


    //==============================================
    // 2)
    //      POPULATE EMPLOYEES
    //==============================================



    let entityEmployee = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Employee", inManagedObjectContext: context)


    let JSONEmployeesString = NSString(contentsOfURL: mURLEmployees!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) as! String

    var dataJSON = JSONEmployeesString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

    var json = JSON(data: dataJSON!)

    if let employees = json["features"].array {
        for employee in employees {

            let employeeObject = Employee(entity: entityEmployee!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

            employeeObject.name = employee["properties"]["NAME"].string!
            employeeObject.companies = employee["properties"]["COMPANIES"].string!

            if !context.save(&error) {
                println("An error occured while saving employees : \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }

        }
    }



    //==============================================
    // 3)
    //      POPULATE COMPANIES
    //==============================================



    let JSONCompaniesString = NSString(contentsOfURL: mURLCompanies!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) as! String

    dataJSON = JSONCompaniesString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

    json = JSON(data: dataJSON!)
    if let companies = json["features"].array {
        for company in companies {


            let employees = company["properties"]["EMPLOYEES"].array!

            var employeeObjects = NSMutableSet()

            for employee in employees {

                let predicateEmployeeName = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", employee.string!)
                let DBRequestEmployeeObject = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")
                DBRequestEmployeeObject.predicate = predicateEmployeeName
                let EmployeeResultArray = context.executeFetchRequest(DBRequestEmployeeObject, error: nil) as! [Employee]
                if let EmployeeResult = EmployeeResultArray.first {
                    employeeObjects.addObject(EmployeeResult)
                } else {
                    println("ERROR")
                }
            }

            let entityCompany = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Company", inManagedObjectContext: context)

            let companyObject = Company(entity: entityCompany!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

            companyObject.name = company["properties"]["NAME"].string!
            companyObject.employees = employeeObjects


            if !context.save(&error) {
                println("An error occured while saving companies : \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }

        }
    }


    //==============================================
    // 4)
    //      RESULT
    //==============================================


    let requestCompanies = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Company")
    let companies = context.executeFetchRequest(requestCompanies, error: nil) as! [Company]
    println("Number of companies : \(companies.count)")

    for company in companies {
        println("\(company.name)")

        for employee in company.employees {
            println("->\(employee.name)")
        }

    }



}
```

And my data model looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Fix your model. The Employee Entity should have a to-many relationship to your Company Entity.

CoreData doesn't like it when a relationship is only defined in one direction.

CoreData is a graph, not a database.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your relationship is many-to-many, in your Employee managedObject you need to have "companies" relationship instead of attribute. then you have to regenerate your managed object subclass.

then create all employee entities (using your loop) without setting the companies relationship.
then create companies and while creating them for each companies fetch the employees then add them to the company companyObject.employees = employeeObjects

Comment: Should the relationship be a reverse of the previous one, or a separate one then?

Comment: reverse, so you can ask employee for his Companies or companies for its employees

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know how it went

Comment: When regenerating the classes, I don't get new methods addEmployees in my subclass. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: it should be there regenerate both classes, sometime you need to delete old ones

Comment: Mmm, I guess it's only available in the newest Xcode beta versions then?

Comment: it should be there for all version...select both entities and under Editor  tap create managed Object subclass

Comment: what is the content of Employee.h and Company.h

Comment: It's actually swift, but I only have the member variables class Company: NSManagedObject {

    (a)NSManaged var name: String
    (a)NSManaged var employees: NSSet

}

Comment: Ok so, just do it with the way you adding employee to company in your code.. it should work. since right now employee can belong to many companies and company can have many employees

Comment: It seems to work :) I'll check a bit more and validate your answer if I don't find anything odd.